# ActiveAdmin / Formtastic Has Many Through with field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, has-many-through, formtastic

I have Users and Groups.

`Users has_many :groups, :through => Membership`
`Groups has_many :users, :through => Membership`

Good so far. Membership now has a boolean field, `manager`.

Users can be managers of groups, and groups can have more than one manager. Everywhere in the site, this works fine and causes no problems. Now they need to administrate this somehow. I'm using Active Admin (Formtastic) and have the fields presented `:as => :check_boxes`.

The users like the check boxes. They want me to put a second check box next to the one that toggles whether a user is in a group to determine if the user is a manager of that group.

How can I possibly go about this? I have tried using the `f.has_many` system, but that creates one entry for each existing membership, provides no way to delete memberships, and isn't what the users want. I want to show EVERY user, show a check box to determine if a Membership exists for that pairing, and show another check box next to it for the value of the manager field.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to have an AJAX call when clicking on the checkbox. Assuming you are using coffeescript for your javacript files and jQuery, to give a general guideline (not tested), use an attribute on your checkbox, like this:

```
<checkbox data-group=<%=group.id%> data-user=<%=user.id%> data-something="true">
```

Then, create a javascript function that takes this data-something and put a function click on it that calls an page:

```
$document.ready ->
  $(["data-something]").click ->
    user = this.attr("data-user")
    group = this.attr("data-group")
    $.post("/some/url", {value: this.value, user: user, group: group})
```

Add the route to this controller, then on action from this url, simple deal with the logic

```
Class SomeController
  def url
    user = User.find(params[:user])
    ....
  end
end
```

If you have more problems, make a more specific question later.